# Twitter Digits check if the authentication was already made

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I managed to integrate twitter digits and the authentication is working, but I want to check if the user already added his number and code.

For now I only have the authentication  part:

```
    final TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new Twitter(authConfig));
```

And the button event:

```
  digitsButton = (DigitsAuthButton) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);
    digitsButton.setCallback(new AuthCallback() {
        @Override
        public void success(DigitsSession session,
                            String phoneNumber) {
            // Do something with the session
            Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this,"Registration Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
            Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this,"Registration Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

-

***How can I check if the user already made these steps?***

Answer (score 1):

You can save the fact that an authentication was successful by storing the data somewhere. [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Using SharedPreferences, to check if an authentication was successful you would use **isAuthenticated** below:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean isAuthenticated = settings.getBoolean("ALREADY_AUTHENTICATED", false);
```

And to set that an authentication was successful (true), you could put this in the callback's **success** method

```
// We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
// All objects are from android.context.Context
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("ALREADY_AUTHENTICATED", true /** or false */);

// Commit the edits!
editor.commit();
```

Comment: How would you identify a Sim card change?